# How to setup JNDI resource in tomcat with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jndi

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA and I'm trying to set up JNDI resource in Tomcat but I'm using intelliJ IDEA. I have done this with Eclipse many times, but as you know there is a separate folder Servers in the project structure that allows you to open the server.xml and set up the JNDI resource. I've looked through the options of Tomcat in IDEA but couldn't find anything. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

You can just edit `server.xml` file in `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/` directory, where `TOMCAT_HOME` is the directory of the Tomcat installation you have configured in *Run/Debug configuration*.

You can open and edit that file in IntelliJ using `File/Open` or just edit it outside of the IDE using vim for instance.

Comment: Yeah, i've already done that, however, I was wondering if there is a way to have several server.xml files for each Tomcat instance...Thanks anyway

Comment: @user3240544 You could create multiple context files, which can contain resource definitions for each of your apps (contexts). More information can be found here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions. Have you tried this approach?

Answer (score 0):

1. Project Structure > Module > Web > Click -> Add Application Server
2. specific descriptor... > Click Tomcat Server > context.xml will make